# Fixing tostring() in Python's lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

lxml's `tostring()` function seems quite broken when printing only parts of documents. Witness:

```
from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring, tostring
frag = fragment_fromstring('<p>This stuff is <em>really</em> great!')
em = frag.cssselect('em').pop(0)
print tostring(em)
```

I expect `<em>really</em>` but instead it prints `<em>really</em> great!` which is **wrong**. The ' great !' is *not* part of the selected `em`. It's not only wrong, it's a pill, at least for processing document-structured XML, where such trailing text will be common.

As I understand it, lxml stores any free text that comes after the current element in the element's `.tail` attribute. A scan of the code for `tostring()` brings me to ElementTree.py's `_write()` function, which clearly always prints the tail. That's correct behavior for whole trees, but not on the last element when rendering a subtree, yet it makes no distinction.

To get a proper tail-free rendering of the selected XML, I tried writing a `toxml()` function from scratch to use in its place. It basically worked, but there are many special cases in handling comments, processing instructions, namespaces, encodings, yadda yadda. So I changed gears and now just piggyback `tostring()`, post-processing its output to remove the offending `.tail` text:

```
def toxml(e):
    """ Replacement for lxml's tostring() method that doesn't add spurious
    tail text. """

    from lxml.etree import tostring
    xml = tostring(e)
    if e.tail:
        xml = xml[:-len(e.tail)]
    return xml
```

A basic series of tests shows this works nicely.

Critiques and/or suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: ping the lxml developers about this, they might integrate your version or at least link to it ;)

Comment: One can surely argue that your fragment isn't good xml, as you have some <p> tag thats never closed. In addition the lxml docs say 'must contain just a single element' which you violate: http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html-fragments

Comment: Actually, I was using lxml.html to process XHTML. Most XHTML in the wild, I find, contains enough variances to throw pure XML tools into conniptions. But the XML tools are powerful, so I try to find ways to use them rather than more HTML-specific tools.

Comment: @schlenk Good catch on the missing </p>. It doesn't change the outcome of tostring() in this instance, but it's clearly bad xml.

Comment: Your complaint should be that cssselect returns the text node following the targeted node, shouldn't it?  Is it really tostring's fault?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about `xml = lxml.etree.tostring(e, with_tail=False)`?

```
from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring
from lxml.etree import tostring
frag = fragment_fromstring('<p>This stuff is <em>really</em> great!')
em = frag.cssselect('em').pop(0)
print tostring(em, with_tail=False)
```

Looks like `with_tail` was added in v2.0; do you have an older version?

Comment: TypeError: tostring() got an unexpected keyword argument 'with_tail'

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe it as added in a more recent version of lxml than you're using? I will edit my answer to include the the exact code that worked for me.

Comment: Oh, very good! I have lxml 2.3beta1, and as you say, if I use lxml.etree.tostring() the with_tail=False works great. Interestingly, if I import lxml.html.tostring(), that DOES NOT work. It throws an exception: TypeError: tostring() got an unexpected keyword argument 'with_tail'

Comment: I will use lxml.etree.tostring(element, with_tail=False) as my default approach. I have also filed a bug with the lxml team asking them to add the with_tail option to lxml.html.tostring()  https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/697961

Comment: I think the lack of support for that option in `html.tostring()` is intentional. `html.tostring()` is intended to serialize an entire HTML document, where, as you note in your question, including the tail is appropriate. When you select your `<em>` tag, you get an element tree back, so you should use `etree.tostring()` instead, where you get the option to omit the tail.

Comment: Perhaps. I think it an odd, asymmetric API choice if XML/etrees are partially serializable yet HTML trees only serializable in toto. But it wouldn't be the first time a set of APIs favored orthogonality above simplicity and parallel structure.